# Zero dollar Commerce orders - payment how-to?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

My commerce site is setup using Stripe Checkout for payment.

It's possible a customer might have a zero-balance cart after discounts are applied to their order.

What are my options to allow the user to checkout without adding their credit card info into Stripe Checkout's overlay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe, like most payment providers will most likely not allow $0 payments.

In this case, the typical approach is to set up the manual gateway in addition to stripe,  and detect if `order.totalPrice` is $0, then simply change the `paymentMethodId` to the manual gateway id as you submit. The manual gateway will happily complete with a $0 total.